# Logging full network connection like in browser

Tags: download, browser, logging

Can I set my browser or download a special application to log/download everything that is going through network while browsing a site?

When I open a website in Firefox, it downloads the files to temporary folders, but I need everything, and by everything I mean full Ajax request logging, image downloading...etc Every file that is downloaded while browsing sites (and not temporary, I need them later, so It should log and categorize it somehow).

Otherwise: I want to automatically save everything you can see in the browser's network tab (after pressing F12) and not just the response, also need the information about what it sent and what it got back.

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is a free program for Windows, Mac OS, and Linux that can monitor and record all network packets to and from your machine including browser and other network traffic. Packet captures can be saved for later viewing.

To use in its simplest form simply select your network interface and start capture. Packets can be viewed and filtered/unfiltered during active capture as well as after you stop, including if you save the capture after previously saving it.

Comment: Isn't wireshark a little too low level tool for logging http packets?

Comment: Nope, Wireshark is an excellent HTTP logging tool.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and other browsers have web developer tools. For Firefox, the "Web Console":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Comment: There is also Opera Dragonfly for Opera browser - I like it more than Firefox tools for develpers.

Comment: I know, but these tools won't log it to a folder, so i can't check it later.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "Webpage, Complete" option via the Save option of the browser should get most of the  page elements in a folder with the same name as the web page title. For dynamically generated web pages, you may get a different set of files related to the main web page, with each viewing.

Some web pages fetch images only when the page is scrolled. For such conditional rendering of page elements, I doubt if any tool exists that would get ALL associated files. I know of web page "leaching" tools that would get all static files for offline access but they may be ineffective in cases where content of the web page is fetched dynamically